# Tkinter: instances in __init__ are not recognised

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, in which pressing each one of three buttons, label2 text should record their state.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.state = [False, False, False]
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.label1 = Label(frame, text="buttons", fg="black").grid(row=0)
        self.buttonR = Button(frame, text="RED", fg="red", command=self.controlR).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.buttonG = Button(frame, text="GREEN", fg="green", command=self.controlG).grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.buttonB = Button(frame, text="BLUE", fg="blue", command=self.controlB).grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.label2 = Label(frame, text="results", fg="black").grid(row=2)

    def controlR(self):
        self.state[0] = not self.state[0]
        self.results()
    def controlG(self):
        self.state[1] = not self.state[1]
        self.results()
    def controlB(self):
        self.state[2] = not self.state[2]
        self.results()

    def results(self):
        color_list = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"]
        my_str = 'button '
        for i in xrange(len(color_list)):
            my_str += color_list[i]
            if self.state[i] == False:
                my_str += " is OFF \n"
            else:
                my_str += " is ON \n"    
        print my_str
        print type(self.label2)  
        self.label2['text'] = my_str

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

What I get is `TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment`
 because each one of the five widgets launched in the *init* definition are not recognized as `instances` in the *results* definition. Thus `print type(self.label2)` returns `NoneType`.

Why does it happen? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in this section of your code:

```
self.label1 = Label(frame, text="buttons", fg="black").grid(row=0)
self.buttonR = Button(frame, text="RED", fg="red", command=self.controlR).grid(row=1, column=0)
self.buttonG = Button(frame, text="GREEN", fg="green", command=self.controlG).grid(row=1, column=1)
self.buttonB = Button(frame, text="BLUE", fg="blue", command=self.controlB).grid(row=1, column=2)
self.label2 = Label(frame, text="results", fg="black").grid(row=2)
```

You're assigned the result of calling the `grid()` method of the widgets, and it returns 'None'. To prevent this, just do something like this with each one of them instead:

```
self.label1 = Label(frame, text="buttons", fg="black")
self.label1.grid(row=0)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.